# How to sum up certain cells in a row based on that adjacent cells

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

```
ID           268                                          287                                          396 
Simulation | Leaving Date | Benefit on Leaving (if any) | Leaving Date | Benefit on Leaving (if any) | Leaving Date | Benefit on Leaving (if any)
1            2040           $50                           2040           $100                          2035
```

I want to sum up the benefits on leaving for each ID for any given year. For example, if I would like to sum up the benefits on leaving for 2035, it would be 0. However, if I were to sum up the benefits on leaving for 2040, it should give $50 + $100 = $150.

How can I do this in Excel? I know how to use `INDEX` & `MATCH` to find a particular leaving date and take the benefit on leaving, which is simply the next cell. However, in some cases, there will not be just one person leaving in that given year (the `INDEX` & `MATCH` method I know of can only search and return unique values). Moreover, for certain IDs, when they leave, they do not receive any benefit, so that corresponding cell is blank, as seen for ID 396.

I would not like to "brute force" this, as what I have shown is only a short example, but in actual fact, the row for each simulation is about 100 columns long (I have about 50 IDs) and I need to do this for 1000 simulations.

In summary,

1. The "Benefit on Leaving (if any)" column always follows a "Leaving Date" column.
2. Each "Leaving Date" column is like my criterion - within each row, I need to find all the "leaving dates" that I am looking for and sum the corresponding benefits on leaving. If there is no benefit on leaving for that leaving date, then I take that specific value to be 0.

Any intuitive suggestions will be greatly appreciated :) and I apologise if a similar question has been asked before! I could not find any satisfactory solutions after much searching.

Comment: Use `SUMIFS` with offset ranges: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuyi4.png. Though, this does assume that no Benefit will be 2040.

Comment: @BigBen Oh, very nice! I did not know that `SUMIFS` could work like that! Yes, I think this will work because the benefits are all huge amounts (in the hundred thousands). If it does not work, then I will be back! Thank you :)

Comment: If you want to be safe, you can use `SUMPRODUCT` with offset ranges. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv7ye.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Use `SUMIFS` with offset ranges (though does assume that no Benefit will be equal to 2040).

```
=SUMIFS(B2:F2,A2:E2,2040)
```

[image]

Option 2: Use `SUMPRODUCT` with offset ranges.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F2*(A1:E1="Leaving Date")*(A2:E2=2040))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I have a follow-up question... Would you have any idea how to return the ID if the leaving date is more than a certain year? For example, if I want to get all the IDs where the leaving date > 2025, then I should return 268, 287 and 396 (whether the result is in a row or column does not really matter to me).

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `FILTER` function?

Comment: Oh yes, but what if I need to share the file later on with people whose Excel does not support that? Will it show an error for them?

Comment: Yes. If you post an additional question (noting that you can't use Dynamic Array formulas), I or someone else should be able to provide a good answer.